# Why not use form action ""?

Tags: php, html, forms

Is is neccessary to use the following?

```
<form method="post" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>
```

Why not `<form method="post" action=""> ?`

Can someone hack `action=""` ?

Comment: Who says you shouldn't use `action=""`?

Comment: Both do the same thing. If `htmlspecialchars()` were omitted, then that would be a different ballgame.

Comment: Why not `<form method="post">`? You don't have to specify an action at all, not even `action=""`.

Comment: What about XSS cross site scripting? Can someone put code in your action="" ?

Answer (score 1):

The action attribute isn't required in this case, only if you were to keep the method's script within another file for example.

I'm not sure what you mean by "Can someone hack action=""" but this has nothing to do with things being hacked, as long as you validate the user input of the post and such you should be fine.

Comment: I see from some sites that If "PHP_SELF" is used in your page then a user can enter a slash (/) and then some Cross Site Scripting (XSS) commands to execute. See this link: http://www.html-form-guide.com/php-form/php-form-action-self.html